# gpg --list-keys output after deleting secret key

Tags: gnupg

I run `gpg --list-keys` and it shows me the keys present in the keyring:

```
/home/kshitiz/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   4096R/8F64D7E0 2015-02-18
uid                  Kshitiz Sharma (http://ksharma.in) <ksharma.android@gmail.com>
sub   4096R/C87EAA9F 2015-02-18
sub   4096R/B63EFB4D 2015-02-18
```

I delete my secret key:

```
$ gpg --delete-secret-key ksharma.android@gmail.com
sec  4096R/8F64D7E0 2015-02-18 Kshitiz Sharma (http://ksharma.in) <ksharma.android@gmail.com>

Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N) y
This is a secret key! - really delete? (y/N) y
```

And then list keys again `gpg --list-keys`. Same output:

```
/home/kshitiz/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   4096R/8F64D7E0 2015-02-18
uid                  Kshitiz Sharma (http://ksharma.in) <ksharma.android@gmail.com>
sub   4096R/C87EAA9F 2015-02-18
sub   4096R/B63EFB4D 2015-02-18
```

**Why didn't the secret key `8F64D7E0` get deleted?**

Weirdly, running `gpg --delete-secret-key` again says key not found:

```
gpg: key "ksharma.android@gmail.com" not found: eof
gpg: ksharma.android@gmail.com: delete key failed: eof
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPG stores public and private keys in different places.

You output mentions : `/home/kshitiz/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` which holds the "public" key (**pub**ring)

If you want to list private keys you have to use the `--list-secret-keys` switch.

As per why the key 8F64D7E0 does not get deleted, it's because you asked to destroy the private key only. Since deleting a private key does not impact the public key, there is no need for it to be cascade deleted.